# What are the steps needed to allow SSL connections with Google PageSpeed Service?

Tags: iis, ssl, cdn, google-pagespeed

I'm currently researching how to implement SSL connections through Google's PageSpeed Service.  I have been accepted into the program; but I'm having issues conceptualizing how SSL connections will work.

I am using IIS 7, and have production certificates already for multiple domains.  Google states you can add up to 50 domains... but did not specify how many could utilize SSL.

1. Will all of my domains be able to serve SSL connections with Google
       PageSpeed?
2. Do I need new SSL certificates?
3. <strike>If not, do I upload the private or public part of the certificate to Google?</strike>
4. <strike>How do I get these keys out of IIS?</strike>
5. Do any certificates from Google need to be installed on my server?

The SSL guide offers little in the way of hand-holding.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/pss/SSLSetup

I'm hoping someone out there has gone through this before and can guide me.

As I said before, we have several domains; and I was planning on using one of the less trafficked sites for SSL testing. I don't want to lock myself out from having the ability to add the more important domains I manage.

Thanks.

Comment: Using MMC I can extract the current certificate out of the Certificates snap-in. Then convert the .pfx with openssl.

Comment: openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out unencrypted.pem -nodes

Comment: Both the private key, and the certificate (contains public key) need to be uploaded to Google per their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 1.Will all of my domains be able to serve SSL 
  connections with Google PageSpeed?
```

**Answer 1**
What I saw in the tutorial is that it supports one single host:

> Before starting the SSL setup, please note that PageSpeed Service
>   supports the following certificate types:
>
> - Single Domain/Hostname
> - Self-signed
> - Wildcard
> - Subject Alternative Name (SAN) / Multi Domain

from https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/pss/SSLSetup

```
2. Do I need new SSL certificates?
```

**Answer 2**
Yes you need a new certificate and you need it to be signed it is described in this part :

**Generating a certificate signing request**
of : https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/pss/setup

```
5. Do any certificates from Google need to be installed on my server?
```

**Answer 5**
No, you need to upload your certificate to Googles server like described in below :

> **5. Upload Certificates**

in https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/pss/SSLSetup

Comment: Mehdi, have you gone through a Google PageSpeed Service setup before?  I've read through the setup guides and they do not illustrate all the steps needed to implement. The latest response I got from Google is that you can only have one SSL domain, since it needs to be the "primary" domain on your Google Apps for Business account. I have multiple domains and each needs SSL support. Also, how does the origin server send data to Google in encrypted format?  I don't see anything in the documentation that states how this part works.

Comment: I did not do it before, did you go through the 6 minutes video in https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/pss/setup ? How does it send the data to Google in encrypted format ? this is the purpose of SSL it send encrypted data that could be decrypted in the other side.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was hoping to speak with someone who has actually gone through the process successfully. I've already gone through the CSR process, and have certificates for my domains.  Am I suppose to generate another one to upload to Google? I thought I was suppose to send my current certificates to Google.  Does Google use these certificates to relay the encrypted information back to the origin domain. If I don't have a wildcard certificate... will this even work?... since origin.domain.com will not be in the list of domains on the cert? Usually its just www.domain.com and domain.com

Comment: For the wildcard certificate you should check with them, but my understanding is that they are requiring a certificate per domain.